# Crossentropyloss Pytorch: Targetsize does not match Torchsize

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, cross-entropy

I want to use the Crossentropyloss of pytorch but somehow my code only works with batchsize 2, so i am asuming there is something wrong with the shapes of target and output.
I get following error:

```
Value Error: Expected target size (50, 2), got torch.Size([50, 3])
```

My targetsize is `(N=50,batchsize=3)` and the output of my model is `(N=50, batchsize=3, number of classes =2)`. Before the output layer my shape is (N=50,batchsize=3,dimensions=64).

How do i need to change the shapes so that the Crossentropyloss works?

Comment: I have posted an answer, but it seems it will not suit your needs. Could you share with us a little more about the model? Is it an RNN? Could you share some code with us?

Comment: Off course.
it is a transformer model for knowledge tracing called SAINT. 
So N is the sequence length of a user answering questions. And for each question you want to predict if the user will answer right or wrong.

Comment: You will need to provide some code, your `nn.Transformer` setup (if you do use this module). We can't guess what the issue is from here.

Comment: I did not use the nn.Transformer set up. Which part do you need? The entire model? The train_epoch function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further information about your model, here's what I would do. You have a many-to-many RNN which outputs `(seq_len, batch_size, nb_classes)` and the target is `(seq_len, seq_len)`. The [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html?highlight=crossentropyloss#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) module can take additional dimensions `(batch_size, nb_classes, d1​, d2​, ..., dK​)` as an input.

You could make it work by permuting the axes, such that the outputted tensor is of shape `(batch_size, nb_classes, seq_len)`. This should make it happen:

```
output = output.permute(0, 2, 1)
```

Additionally, your target will also have to change to be `(batch_size, seq_len)`:

```
target = target.permute(1, 0)
```

Comment: No N is the number of values i want to predict. 
In this case it is the sequence length of a user answering questions. And for each question you want to make a prediction if a user will answers right or wrong. The model is a transformer model by the way.